# Text with both a superscript and a subscript in Microsoft Visio 2013

Tags: microsoft-visio, equations

I wonder how to add text with both a superscript and a subscript in Microsoft Visio 2013.

Example:

[image]

I am aware of the fact I [could use](https://superuser.com/a/1022918/116475) Microsoft Word Equation Editor for that purpose:

[image]

but the exported file looks really not so neat:

[image]

so I am looking for an alternate solution.

I use Microsoft Visio 2013 Professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use 3 text blocks, put the y, (x) and 1 into the 3 blocks, set the font size for the superscript and subscript blocks, resize and postion the blocks, then group them. You then have full control over the super/sub-script sizing and their relative postions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution. Write some text including subscript and superscript in one line. Then select what you want to be superscript, right click on that selected text, and click on **Font** from context menu which appears. You will get new dialog with different settings. Select **Position**, and then you can either choose Subscript or Superscript.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is to set up your text properly in Word and simply copy and paste it into Visio, it keeps the sub/superscript you've applied in Word.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain how to ‘‘properly’’ format text in Word so that the superscript is *over* the subscript, and not above and to the right (or above and to the left).  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.